# how to run package's composer scripts automaticly

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I have scripts in my package
and I need it to run automaticly but it doesn't

```
"scripts": {
    "pre-package-install": [
        "bash vendor\\DPCO\\DPAdmin\\laravel_version_check.sh"
    ]
}
```

Comment: This is a shell script!!!

Comment: @sta - What's your point? _"A script, in Composer's terms, can either be a PHP callback (defined as a static method) **or any command-line executable command**"_ - From [composers docs](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/scripts.md#what-is-a-script-)